# Blackberry MediaPlayer retrieves empty metaData

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I have a cascades project where I use the MediaPlayer class in cpp.
I have defined a handler class, which handles metaDataChanged event, but when I  set the source url and call mediaPlayer.prepare() method, it doesn't retrieve anything in metadata, so it's simply empty QVariantMap.

What's interesting is that defined event handler for metaDataChaned event is not even called.

I think there could be something that I can add here to be able to get the metadata, however prepare() method workds sucessfully, so I don't know what's the problem

here is a piece of code I've tried.

```
    bb::multimedia::MediaPlayer* mp = new bb::multimedia::MediaPlayer();
    mp->setSourceUrl(resultString);
    mp->prepare();
    MetaDataReader metaDataReader(mp);
```

and a class

```
    MetaDataReader::MetaDataReader(bb::multimedia::MediaPlayer* mediaPlayer) : QObject(NULL)
    {
        connect(mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(metaDataChanged(const QVariantMap&)), this, SLOT(onMetaDataChanged(const QVariantMap&)));
    }

    void MetaDataReader::onMetaDataChanged(const QVariantMap& metaData)
    {
        someCode

            // It doesn't reach this SLOT
    }
```

How can I get the metadata here?

thanks in advance

Comment: can add the piece of code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd, but you may not get metadata until you start playback for the file. Try starting playback, and you should see the `metaDataChanged` signal get fired shortly after.